# Add Meta Audience Network as an AdMob Mediation Network in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, admob, build.gradle, facebook-audience-network

I'm trying to integrate AdMob mediation networks (specifically Meta Audience Network) into Flutter, I added the "google_mobile_ads" package (https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads).

There are two things I would like to ask:

1. I followed the initial integration documentation (https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/quick-start#platform_specific_setup) which says "See the Android guide for more information on configuring AndroidManifest.xml and setting app ID". In that link it shows other steps to do, should I do them or does the plugin itself (same question for iOS)? (I wonder why I haven't made them at the moment and it seems to work)
2. If I want to add Meta Audience Network, I go to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/meta#android_studio_integration_recommended), but I don't understand which build.gradle I need to put that dependency on. In the "Get Started" that I linked earlier, the google and mavenCentral repositories are added in the build.gradle project, but in this last link of the mediation network it is written that I need to add the dependency in the build.gradle of the app and it also shows the google and mavenCentral repositories which I have in the build.gradle project.
   I get a little confused with Flutter's two build.gradles, could you tell me where I need to add the dependencies?

build.gradle (progetto)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "my_application_id"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

ps. I also tried to contact official support but they replied that they don't deal with this (although it seems strange to me, in fact I replied https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/gS9bAD1Y7FA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No the rest of it will be handled by plugin it self (Before i said yes because miss-understand your question about App-ID in manifest)
2. All you need to do is add `implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.11.0.1'` in build.gradle (app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    //Here 
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.11.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Point 1 is not really correct, there are some things that are not necessary (https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/620)